# Retrieve only matched sub document from MongoLab/MongoDB through http/REST

Tags: mongodb, rest

Is it possible to retrieve only sub document from an object array in MongoDB collection which matches specified query Using **REST HTTP interface**.

There are many already answer for similar questions, but those are for using MongoDB driver, not REST/HTTP

Any possibility ?

Sample data

```
    [
       {
          "name":"Paul",
          "addresses":[
             {
                "addressline1":"Street no1",
                "city":"Delhi"
             },
             {
                "addressline1":"Street no4",
                "city":"Chennai"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "name":"Rose",
          "addresses":[
             {
                "addressline1":"Street no5",
                "city":"Delhi"
             },
             {
                "addressline1":"Street no7",
                "city":"Chennai"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

From above data I only need to get single address, which 'name' matching 'Paul' and 'city' matching 'Delhi' as below

```
    {
          "addressline1":"Street no1",
          "city":"Delhi"
    }
```

I have below query to search within sub document. But it returns all elements in sub document array which contains this sub document query.

```
    https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/[mydb]/collections/[mycollection?
    apiKey=[myAPIKey]
    &q={"name":"Paul","addresses.city":{"$regex":"^Delhi$","$options":"i"}}
    &f={"addresses":1}
```

But above query returns

```
    {      
          "addresses":[
             {
                "addressline1":"Street no1",
                "city":"Delhi"
             },
             {
                "addressline1":"Street no4",
                "city":"Chennai"
             }
          ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
https://...&f={"addresses.$":1}
```

Note that I used the [**`$` projection operator**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) in the query above.